# The count should reset when the name changes

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

My target is the count should reset when the name has changed. As we can see in table 1, the count continues even the name changed.

**My current output:**

| id | name | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | juan | 1 |
| 2 | juan | 2 |
| 3 | juan | 3 |
| 4 | dela | 4 |
| 5 | dela | 5 |
| 6 | dela | 6 |
| 7 | cruz | 7 |
| 8 | cruz | 8 |
| 9 | cruz | 9 |
| 10 | cruz | 10 |
| 11 | cruz | 11 |

**My target output:**

| id | name | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | juan | 1 |
| 2 | juan | 2 |
| 3 | juan | 3 |
| 4 | dela | 1 |
| 5 | dela | 2 |
| 6 | dela | 3 |
| 7 | cruz | 1 |
| 8 | cruz | 2 |
| 9 | cruz | 3 |
| 10 | cruz | 4 |
| 11 | cruz | 5 |

As we can see here in table 2, the count reset because the name changes.

**Controller:**

```
public function lists()
    {
        
        
        $list = $this->lists->get_datatables();
        $json = array();
        $no = $_POST['start'];
        $count = '1';
        foreach ($list as $list) {
            
       
            $no++;
           $row = array();
            $row[] = '<tr><td>'.$list->id.'</td>';
            $row[] = '<tr><td>'.$list->Name.'</td>';
            $row[]='<td>'. $count++.'</td>';
 
            
            $data[] = $row;
            
        }
        
        $output = array(
            "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
            "recordsTotal" => $this->lists->count_all(),
            "recordsFiltered" => $this->lists->count_filtered(),
            "data" => $data,
        );
        //output to json format
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
public function lists()
{
    
    
    $list = $this->lists->get_datatables();
    $json = array();
    $no = $_POST['start'];
    $count = '1';

    $check_arr = array();

    foreach ($list as $list) {
       

       if(!empty($check_arr) && !in_array($list->Name, $check_arr))  {         
         $count = 1;
       }

       $no++;
       $row = array();
       $row[] = '<tr><td>'.$list->id.'</td>';
       $row[] = '<tr><td>'.$list->Name.'</td>';
       $row[]='<td>'. $count++.'</td>';

       $check_arr[] = $list->Name;
        
    }
    
    $output = array(
        "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
        "recordsTotal" => $this->lists->count_all(),
        "recordsFiltered" => $this->lists->count_filtered(),
        "data" => $data,
    );
    //output to json format
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. What a savior.

Comment: Is it okay if I ask for your explanation regarding your answer? Since I'm studying... Your explanation will help me a lot to understand more.

Comment: @UlquiorraSchiffer he resets `$count = 1` when there's a new element not in the array . That's check by this: `!in_array($list->Name, $check_arr)`. `$count = 1` when the first element of the array, too: `!empty($check_arr)`